# I need same height on <li> tag from diffrent <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two  with the same number of li. If the second li from first  it's change height, I want the second  to change height for li in the second position. I started a JQuery script but not sure how to check each li.

```
<li data-target="dynamic">
<ul>
    <li>item 1<br>3</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li data-target="dynamic">
 <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

javascript

```
$('[data-target="dynamic"]').each(function(){
   $(this).find('li').each(function(n){
      $(this).attr('data-position', n);
   });
});

$('[data-position]').each(function(){
  var height = $(this).height();
  console.log($(this),height);     
});
```

I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6yL6fdt7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this... I'm not very sure what you want to achieve, but I hope that I guessed right

http://jsfiddle.net/6yL6fdt7/3/

```
function align(first, second) {
    var f = first.find('li');
    var s = second.find('li');

    for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        var first_li = $(f[i]);
        var second_li = $(s[i]);
        if (first_li.height() > second_li.height())
            second_li.height(first_li.height());
        else if (first_li.height() < second_li.height())
            second_li.height(first_li.height());
    }
}

align($('#one'), $('#two'));
```

Comment: This does not dynamically do it

Comment: @SamBattat it does, just assign function to event you want it to trigger

Comment: If I change a li from $('#two'), it's not change in $('#one').

Answer (score 1):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6yL6fdt7/2/)**

```
var highest='';
$('[data-target="dynamic"]').each(function(){

    //find the highest li
    $(this).find('li').each(function(n){
        if(highest==''){
            highest=$(this);
        }
        else{
            if(highest.height()<$(this).height()){
                highest=$(this);
            }
        }
    });

    //set all the lis hight as the highest one
    $(this).find('li').height(highest.height());
});
```

Comment: This adds the height to all elements not just the matching order

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general solution (not just for 2 `li`s )

```
var heights = [];
$('[data-target="dynamic"]').each(function(){
   $(this).find('li').each(function(n){
      $(this).attr('data-position', n);
      if(heights[n] == undefined)
        heights[n] = $(this).height();
      else if(heights[n] < $(this).height())
        heights[n] = $(this).height();
   });
});
$('li[data-position]').each(function(){
    var n = parseInt($(this).attr('data-position'));
    $(this).height(heights[n]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<ul class="fixed">` and `<ul class="dynamic">` (and of course that both have the same amount of `<li>`)

```
var fixed = $('.fixed > ul > li');
var dynamic = $('.dynamic > ul > li');

fixed.each(function(index, element) {
    dynamic[index].style.height = element.offsetHeight + 'px';
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6yL6fdt7/7/

Answer (score 0):

To do match the height of matching li (just like you asked) you can do the following, so if the first li has a larger height then only adjust the first on the second ul

```
var biggerH = $("li[data-target=dynamic] ul li:first-child").height();
var nth = 0;
$("li[data-target=dynamic] ul li").each(function(i){
    $("li[data-target=dynamic] ul li").each(function(k){
        if(biggerH < $(this).height()){
            biggerH = $(this).height();
            nth = k;
        }
    });
});
$("li[data-target=dynamic] ul li:nth-child("+nth+")").height(biggerH);
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/6yL6fdt7/5/